# How do I update the value of a custom attribute (enum-of-strings) in SFCC via code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, demandware

Requirement: I want to update the value of a custom attribute (name: badges) (type: enum-of-strings) for a Product via code. I want to set the value "bestSeller" as selected. How should I do that update because the code below is not working?

[Screenshot of the Custom Attribute in Business Manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zFxba.png)

Code snippet:

```
function updateBestSeller() {
var ProductMgr = require('dw/catalog/ProductMgr');
var Site = require('dw/system/Site');
var UUIDUtils = require('dw/util/UUIDUtils');
var CustomObjectMgr = require('dw/object/CustomObjectMgr');
var currentSite = Site.getCurrent();
var bestSellerOrderUnits = Object.hasOwnProperty.call(currentSite.preferences.custom, 'bestSellerOrderUnits') ? currentSite.getCustomPreferenceValue('bestSellerOrderUnits') : 0;
try {
        Transaction.wrap(function () {
            var count = 1;
            var products = ProductMgr.queryAllSiteProducts();sni
            var HashSet = require('dw/util/HashSet');
             var badges = new HashSet();
            if (products.count > 0) {
                while (products.hasNext() && count < 5) {
                    var product = products.next();
                        var badges = [];
                        badges.push('bestSeller');
                        if (Object.hasOwnProperty.call(product.custom, 'badges')) {
                            product.custom.badges = badges
                        }
                        count++;
                        Logger.debug('{0}',product.ID);
                }
            }
            products.close();
        });
} catch (ex) {
    Logger.error(ex.toString());
    return new Status(Status.ERROR, 'ERROR', 'UPDATE failed');
}
return new Status(Status.OK, 'OK', 'UPDATE successful');
```

}

Answer (score 2):

I think what is probably happening here is that your attempt to validate that a product has a `badges` key in the `product.custom` attribute collection is failing. This prevents the update from occurring.

I suggest removing the condition around the following line:
`product.custom.badges = badges;`

If that line were to not execute, then the update to the database would never occur.

The way custom attributes work is that they will never exist until a value is set for that attribute for a given persistent object. (eg: Product) So checking to see if it exists via something like: `'badges' in product.custom` (which is the recommended way) will often be `false` even when the custom attribute definition exists because many products have never had a badge value set. Once an object has had a value set to a particular custom attribute even if it is now set to `null` then it will exist.

Additionally, there are some other issues with the code that may be causing problems. One example is defining the `badges` variable twice within the same scope. Another example is `sni` that is placed at the end of the line where you define the `products` variable. This is likely causing an error in your code. Finally, it is a good practice to avoid the use of the `queryAllSiteProducts` method if you can. An alternative may be to use the [`ProductSearchModel`](https://documentation.b2c.commercecloud.salesforce.com/DOC1/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.demandware.dochelp%2FDWAPI%2Fscriptapi%2Fhtml%2Fapi%2Fclass_dw_catalog_ProductSearchModel.html) instead; This may not always meet your need, but it is a good idea to rule it out before resorting to `queryAllSiteProducts` for performance reasons.

Something else to consider is that if `badges` currently has any selected values, you'll be overwriting those values with the code you have today. Consider setting `badges` initially to `[]` then check to see if there *is* a value for that product by doing:

```
if ('badges' in product.custom && !empty(product.custom.badges) {
  badges = product.custom.badges;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @sholsinger. 'csutomerperperty' in product.custom - important check, we always miss.